# Some programs look weird

Tags: 18.04, graphics

Its hard to explain.

[image: Virtualbox]

Programs look big on one monitor but text is impossible on the other.I have the newest NVIDIA drivers but I don't think they are the problem. This used to not happen. Other programs like flight gear can't even fit on the screen

Comment: Which flavor of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: ubuntu studio is what im using